# Can i use IP address in URL properties of Windows Media Player in VB6.0?

Tags: vb6, ip-address, windows-media-player, wmp

I am trying to make a client server connection in vb 6.0 and stream video in server machine from a client machine.. my doubt is, can i keep the URL in properties of Windows media player as an "IP address" of client machine???
eg.

```
    Const FILE_TO_OPEN = "\\127.0.0.1\C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv"
    Wmp1.URL = FILE_TO_OPEN
```

(instead of 127.0.0.1 ,any IP address in the network can be used)
So far what i have created is, i have connected the server and client using winsock... after connecting i need to access the video file present in client's machine and play that video in wmp of server machine.

If i use it without IP address, that is, if i play a video present in the same machine its working(without connecting client-server)
eg.

```
  Const FILE_TO_OPEN = "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv"
    Wmp1.URL = FILE_TO_OPEN
```

If i cannot use IP ADDRESS IN THAT PLACE, WHAT ELSE AND HOW CAN I USE IT??? any suggestions are welcome... thanks in advance!!

Comment: \\ is a UNC path; do you mean to access the files using Microsoft Networking shares?

Comment: ya you are right.. i want to access a system's video file, connected in Wi-fi or a LAN from my system... please help me out!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't that clear what you actually want to achieve but UNC paths can be used to access any SMB/Samba/Windows share over the network.
You can use IP addresses in place of any (resolvable) name in a UNC, but the UNC path you gave is most likely invalid.
If you're referring to a local path, you can either use the local machine name and public share name or just use a local path.

If your data is available over some other transport (HTTP, RTSP, carrier pigeon, etc) then you need to use an appropriate URL and scheme.

Update:
On rereading it, it sounds liek you want to transfer the video using your own socker ("server and client using winsock") for whihc media player won;t have any idea about unless you make it use one of the standards like HTTP, RTP or SMB. Your best bet is to use one of these known formats.

Comment: ohh. ok thank you... i dont know how to begin with using HTTP and all... can you please help me with that??? you are right, i'm trying to connect server client using winsock and stream video... but i have no idea of how to achieve it... :( pls helpppp meeeeee :(

Comment: It's not something that can be taught here. I do it as a job and what we have has been developed and improved over the last 10 years. It's probably better for you to string together various media player, media server and IIS components rather then try and handle streaming yourself.  
Having said that, do some research on HTTP/RTSP video streaming and the associated formats.